# Can I apply both absolute and relative positional encoding to a Transformer model?

Tags: deep-learning, encoding, embedding, transformer-model

I'm trying to make my own Transformer model. I found that the currently popular models have abandoned absolute position encoding and adopted relative position encoding. However, others told me that I could use both methods of position encoding. Is this OK? Will this hurt the model? Thanks!

I tried to find relevant information online, but there was no apparent result.

Answer (score 0):

You can get some intuation from [Towards data science post](https://towardsdatascience.com/master-positional-encoding-part-ii-1cfc4d3e7375),
He remodify **absolute positional** encoding to be **relative one**, and compare with l**earnable relative** positional encoding.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to apply both of them in the same model, it is not necessary, because one of them is sufficient. In the case of utilizing both of them in the same model/problem, the computation will increase.

So, regarding the difference between Absolute and Relative, from my own experience, the Relative is superior and recommended due to being more efficient. However, it still has some problems in inference.

Recently, the [Rotary positional encoding](https://medium.com/@ngiengkianyew/understanding-rotary-positional-encoding-40635a4d078e) has been introduced by leveraging both Absolute and Relative approaches, solving the problems associated with both.